# Bash command for sorting file by column (large integers - 64 bits)

Tags: bash, sorting

I was searching the web now for a while but I didnt manage to find a solution, so I have to ask you guys.

So is there a shell command which allows me sorting integers of 64 bits? Because if I have file "example.txt":

```
5537074357 14
14078473981 59
10857248511 57
2231666233 0
1242107078 7
3389590707 4
```

And then I apply the command:

```
sort -k 1 example.txt
```

Then I get the following result:

```
10857248511 57
1242107078 7
14078473981 59
2231666233 0
3389590707 4
5537074357 14
```

Which is of course not correct so I guessed it is because I am dealing with really large interger numbers

Comment: Have you tried `sort -n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the sort command does a text sort.  Thus a 10 digit number can appear after an 11 digit number, depending on the ASCII values in the numbers.  If you want to perform a numeric sort, use the -n option (--numeric-sort also works):

```
sort -k 1 -n example.txt
```

Results:

```
1242107078 7
2231666233 0
3389590707 4
5537074357 14
10857248511 57
14078473981 59
```

Comment: OH ok i was not aware of that I guess I should have read the man page more in detail. thank you a lot